# Azure Function with Powershell - Service Bus Queue Output Binding With ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azureservicebus

We are using an Azure Function with Powershell in order to read messages from a Service Bus Queue. It operates with a Service Bus Queue Trigger. We would need to have an output binding in order to write messages into a difference Service Bus Queue. We are able to push the messages using `Push-OutputBinding`. We also need to have a feature to Scheduled the queue message to the Service Bus. Is there a way to set to `ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc` property for the messages in the output binding?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below findings to

> Is there a way to set to `ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc` property for the messages in the output binding?

As Per these GitHub Issues - [Enhancement: Add Scheduled Queue Messages to Service Bus Binding Documentation](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/454) and [ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc setting is not respected](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/10969). it seems to be not supported this feature yet.

But there are few references that shows to use the Proper `ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc` value on `BrokeredMessage`  instance in an output binding and you'll need to use `ICollector` for this output binding.

References:

1. [Azure Functions Service Bus Queue Trigger Output Binding - ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47418664)
2. [Delay a message in the Service Bus Queue from being processed until a scheduled time with NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36362512/delay-a-message-in-the-service-bus-queue-from-being-processed-until-a-scheduled)
3. [Reliably Processing Azure Service Bus Topics with Azure Functions](https://www.alexjamesbrown.com/blog/development/reliably-processing-azure-service-bus-topics-with-azure-functions/)